# PHP - Como posso descobrir o endereço ipv4 do wampserver no modo online?

Tags: php

O que acontece é que estou utilizando websockets e acessando em outros aparelhos pelo modo online do wampserver, eu acesso em redes diferentes, com isso toda vez ele altera o ipv4.
Existe alguma maneira de pegar e por exemplo, redirecionar para esse ip?

Comment: muito confuso e vago o que explicou mas acho que compreendi.. você tem um apache instalado num pc ou notebook, enfim, algo que de alguma forma vc está sempre conectando numa rede diferente, certo ? Então o que vc quer fazer é os dispositivos da rede conectarem no seu pc ou note por meio do ip mas que seja algo automático por meio de um IP ou um nome que redirecionasse para o "server portátil". É isso ?

Comment: Sim! Eu preciso descobrir o ipv4 pra abrir no navegador de um celular por exemplo.

Comment: qual a dificuldade em ver ip pelo cmd usando o ipconfig /all ?  Não seria muito mais simples? Tendo o ip, basta informar a pessoa com o celular ou outro dispositivo , acessar pelo ip ...

Comment: Eu faço isso, mas outras pessoas usarão esse sistema e pensei que se conseguisse pegar automaticamente seria melhor.

Comment: pois é, não rola.. a não ser que registre o seu pc/note nessas redes terceiras. Teria que mudar todos de ip automático para ip estático.. Dá um trabalho e tanto. Dependendo das estruturas e condições, muitas vezes  é invasivo demais ou inviável.. Talvez, algo mais simples, se vc não quer ter o trabalho de abrir o cmd e tal, então execute isso <?php echo getHostByName(getHostName());?>  sempre que entrar numa rede e já deixa o browser aberto com letra bem grande.. há sim meios de resolver como quer mas vai dar mais trabalho

Comment: Na verdade isso resolveu meu problema! Ele retornou o meu ipv4 atual: 192.168.1.8